# How to copy some specific SMS content into clipboard?

Tags: android, regex, sms, clipboard

The bank that I'm working with sends me an SMS containing a random generated six digit code whenever I want to enter for checking my accounts. And everytime it is really tiring to type it manually. I'm thinking about making a little application in order to copy that six digit number into the clipboard so that I paste it instantly to the related field whenever an SMS arrives. Could you please  share your ideas on this subject with me?

Thanks,
YB