# How to copy six digit code from sms and paste anywhere in app in android

Tags: android, sms

I am working on an app in which i am using SMS API for getting the 6 digits verification code.Everything is working good , but now my condition is i want to copy the only 6 digits (ex. your otp is : **676860**).

I have serached many solutions on google ,i used **ClipboardManager** , but that is only useful for copying and pasting the data within the app only.

I checked following link also , but i didn't get the satisfactory answer.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722005/how-to-copy-some-specific-sms-content-into-clipboard)

Can anyone suggest me or help me ,what should i use for copying and pasting 6 digit code from phone SMS to any app .

Answer will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/06/reading-incoming-message-automatically-to-verify-OTP.html

Comment: instead of copy paste, you might want to make it a url that deep link to your app

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorial that helps beginner. just go through those tutorial. those are well explained. like this [Simplified coding](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sms-verification-app-phone-verification-with-otp/) and [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/).

you need to purchase sms gateway. if you are doing for study purposes then search free/cheaper gateways like [msg91](/questions/tagged/msg91)

Comment: thanks for your reply but we are using sms gateway api for that , everthing is working my otp is also coming but now i want  to copy the particular digit

Comment: give field for OTP, user will enter their OTP why you want to copy from msg directly?

Comment: this all things has been done already, but now if suppose any user want to copy the code expect writing it so it can be done